# Better way to handle multiple OR statements

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a better way to write this code in Swift? I am filtering newsCore based on the contents of activeSources array.

```
let foundSources = newsCore.filter { $0[3] as! String == activeSources[0] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[1] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[2] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[3] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[4] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[5] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[6] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[7] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[8] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[9] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[10] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[11] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[12] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[13] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[14] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[15] || $0[3] as! String == activeSources[16]}
```

Comment: Are there other values for `activeSources`? I mean should it match any value in `activeSources`, or do you have more than 17 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contains` instead of or-ing array items individually

```
let foundSources = newsCore.filter { activeSources.contains($0[3] as! String) }
```

> Tip:Think of a proper data type/model instead of `$0[3] as! String`

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful! I'm not sure what you mean with proper data type/model, though. I am still learning Swift .

Comment: i mean it appears that the nested array item inside `newsCore` is of type `Any` and if you force-unwrap with `!` why not to define intiially as `String`

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will try to do this. Much appreciated!